# minimum strength of the edges occurring in any path P

Tags: graph-theory, optimization

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph and let $s: E \to \mathbb{R}^+$ be a function. Let us call $s(e)$ the strength of the edge $e$. For any path $P$ in $G$, the reliability of $P$ is, by definition, the minimum strength of the edges occurring in $P$. The reliability $rG(u,v)$ of two vertices $u$ and $v$ is equal to the maximum reliability of $P$, where $P$ ranges over all paths from $u$ to $v$.

Let $T$ be a spanning tree of maximum strength, i.e, with $\sum_{e \in ET} s(e)$ as large as possible. (Here $ET$ is the set of edges of $T$.) So $T$ can be found with any maximum spanning tree algorithm.

Now $T$ has the same reliability as $G$, for each pair of vertices $u$, $v$. That is:
$$      rT(u,v)=rG(u,v) \, \text{for each $u,v\in V$}$$
Please help me to prove the above statement.

Comment: It's possible to do this using Prim's algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm).  In this algorithm, vertices get included one after another - the vertex inserted has the strongest edge that has an end on the included vertices, and one end not in.  Suppose that $u$ is included before $v$, and look at the iteration in whcih $v$ is included.

Comment: hi.thanks for your help . I tried but did not succeed. please help me . I need this answer Immediately